# Error Message Count Script function not found in google apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

google-apps-script:

I have never used this script and don't even know if I'm asking the right question. I keep getting a notification and I don't know why. Please help me in trying to get rid of receiving this message. Here it is.

> Your script, Copy of Transfer Gmail - Digital Inspiration, has
>   recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is
>   shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your
>   setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.
>
> The script is used by the document Copy of Transfer My Gmail - Digital
>   Inspiration.
>
> Summary:
>
> ```
> Error Message                         Count
> Script function not found: forwardMail    24
> Start             Function    Error Message                           Trigger     End
> 1/26/18 5:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/26/18 5:38 PM
> 1/26/18 6:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/26/18 6:38 PM
> 1/26/18 7:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/26/18 7:38 PM
> 1/26/18 8:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/26/18 8:38 PM
> 1/26/18 9:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/26/18 9:38 PM
> 1/26/18 10:38 PM  forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/26/18 10:38 PM
> 1/26/18 11:38 PM  forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/26/18 11:38 PM
> 1/27/18 12:38 AM  forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 12:38 AM
> 1/27/18 1:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 1:38 AM
> 1/27/18 2:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 2:38 AM
> 1/27/18 3:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 3:38 AM
> 1/27/18 4:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 4:38 AM
> 1/27/18 5:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 5:38 AM
> 1/27/18 6:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 6:38 AM
> 1/27/18 7:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 7:38 AM
> 1/27/18 8:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 8:38 AM
> 1/27/18 9:38 AM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 9:38 AM
> 1/27/18 10:38 AM  forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 10:38 AM
> 1/27/18 11:38 AM  forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 11:38 AM
> 1/27/18 12:38 PM  forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 12:38 PM
> 1/27/18 1:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 1:38 PM
> 1/27/18 2:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 2:38 PM
> 1/27/18 3:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 3:38 PM
> 1/27/18 4:38 PM   forwardMail Script function not found: forwardMail  time-based  1/27/18 4:38 PM
> ```
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Google Apps Script
>
> Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. Please do not
>   reply to this message. (c) 2018 Google

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed an add-on like the one mentioned on [Transfer your Gmail Messages to Another Email Address](https://www.labnol.org/internet/transfer-gmail/28088/). If so, uninstall the related add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Author of the script here.

The failure notifications likely occur when a Google Script is deleted from your Drive without de-authorisation or when the permissions get revoked for some reason.

You need to access all your existing triggers inside the Apps Script Editor and remove the one that is triggering these notifications.

See: [Unsubscribe from Google Apps Script Emails](https://ctrlq.org/docs/20474-summary-failures-google-apps-script)